# 403 forbidden nginx on docker/ddev website

Tags: docker, drupal, wsl-2

I am attempting to deploy a site locally with Docker with DDev, using WSL2. I have gotten as far as getting phpMyAdmin working, and I have a ddev url, but when I try to use `ddev launch` and/or goto the http://sitename.ddev.site I get a 403 error.

So far I have tried to change docroot to public and that didn't work. Additionally I have SSH'd into the docker container, and all of the appropriate files are there. My directory hierarchy looks like (using ls in the powershell):

`~/dev/project_name$ ls`

`composer.json composer.lock project_name public sites vendor`

Additionally, and this may be a separate question and possibly unrelated - but in the event that it isn't - when I run the drupal installation command with:

`ddev exec drush site:install --account-name=admin --account-pass=admin`

I get asked for database name/driver/username/password/host/port - of which I'm not totally sure what information it expects me to supply. I managed to find the database information in Docker, but I haven't been able to correctly supply it the correct information, apparently. The input and output:

````
 Database name [drupal]:
 > db

 Database driver [mysql]:
 > mysql

 Database username [drupal]:
 > db

 Database password [drupal]:
 > root

 Database host [127.0.0.1]:
 > localhost

 Database port [3306]:
 > 3306

 [warning] Program UNKNOWN not found. Proceed if you have already created or emptied the Drupal database.

 Do you want to continue? (yes/no) [yes]:
 > yes

 [notice] Starting Drupal installation. This takes a while.
 [notice] Performed install task: install_select_language
 [notice] Performed install task: install_select_profile
 [notice] Performed install task: install_load_profile
 [notice] Performed install task: install_verify_requirements

In install.core.inc line 971:

  Database name field is required.
  Database username field is required.
  Resolve all issues below to continue the installation. For help configuring your database server, see the <a href="https://www.dr
  upal.org/docs/8/install">installation handbook</a>, or contact your hosting provider.<div class="item-list"><ul><li>Failed to con
  nect to your database server. The server reports the following message: <em class="placeholder">SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such fi
  le or directory</em>.<ul><li>Is the database server running?</li><li>Does the database exist or does the database user have suffi
  cient privileges to create the database?</li><li>Have you entered the correct database name?</li><li>Have you entered the correct
   username and password?</li><li>Have you entered the correct database hostname and port number?</li></ul></li></ul></div>


Failed to execute command drush site:install --account-name=admin --account-pass=admin: exit status 1```
````

Answer (score 1):

The next notice should be this:

> [notice] Performed install task: install_verify_database_ready

Maybe the database is down, not connected, or the **access data is wrong**.

### Check the drush status:

```
ddev exec drush st
```

> Drupal version   : 9.3.2
> Site URI         : http://my-drupal9-site.ddev.site
> DB driver        : mysql
> DB hostname      : ddev-my-drupal9-site-db
> DB port          : 3306
> DB username      : db
> DB name          : db
> Database         : Connected

## Steps to reproduce, without the error

### install brew

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

### install ddev

```
brew install drud/ddev/ddev
```

### start container

```
cd ~/dockertests/

mkdir my-drupal9-site
cd my-drupal9-site
ddev config --project-type=drupal9 --docroot=web --create-docroot
ddev start
ddev composer create "drupal/recommended-project"
ddev composer require drush/drush
ddev drush site:install -y
ddev drush uli
ddev launch
# [success] Installation complete.  User name: admin  User password: XXXX
```

### install drupal again

```
ddev exec drush site:install --account-name=admin --account-pass=admin
```

Comment: What if you are cloning a repo from git?

Comment: the crucial point I had missed following the docs was `--docroot=web`